# assigning a value to members in a list in python

Tags: python, list

i have a list , lets say :

```
test = [False, False, 2, False, False, False, 3, False, False]
```

and i want to assign every member of this list to False unless this member is equal to 2
so the result should be :

```
test = [False, False, 2, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

i tried :

```
test = [False for i in test if i !=2]
```

but the result was :

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

and i try to define a function :

```
def set_False(lst):
     for i in lst:
         if i != 2:
            i = False
    return lst
```

and when i apply :

```
test = set_False(test)
```

the result was:

```
[False, False, 2, False, False, False, 3, False, False]
```

i can't use enumerate in the environment where i am putting my code  , so any suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `enumerate`? It's a core Python built-in function.

Comment: because i am working in a some environment that has python 2.5 , and it is giving me error that enumerate is not defined .

Comment: `enumerate` has been in the language since 2.3: http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's

```
[False if i !=2 else 2 for i in test]
```

Otherwise, you're skipping the whole element when it's equal to 2.

Comment: [(i, False)[i != 2]  for i in test] would work too, but it's ugly ;)

Comment: @lvaldi: why are you even mentioning it then?

Comment: I find this slightly better, as it decouples the condition from the default assignment `[i if i==2 else False for i in test]`. This allows you to wrap in a function that would take a condition argument, and write (shown here as a lambda because I'm in a comment): `false_filter = lambda condition, seq: [i if condition(i) else False for i in seq]`  Your code then becomes `test = false_filter(lambda x:x==2, test)`.

Answer (score 3):

In your case modifying in place can be done this way:

```
   for i in range(len(lVals)):
       if lVals[i] != 2:
           lVals[i] = False
```

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python27/web/list-comprehensions.html) might be the most pythonic way to achieve your goal :

```
myList = [False, False, 2, False, False, False, 3, False, False]
myFilteredList = [False if i !=2 else i for i in myList]
```

If you do not want to use such a syntax, another approch is to use a [mapping function](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python27/web/map-function.html) :

```
def myFilter(i):
   return False if i!=2 else i

myList = [False, False, 2, False, False, False, 3, False, False]
myFilteredList = map( myFilter, myList )
```